# Autosys exit code meaning

Tags: ca, autosys

I'm studying CA autosys and I met a condition formula like
Condition: e(job1,06.00) = 0 & e(job2,03.00) = 0.
I know the exit code 0 means success. Then what does "06.00" and "03.00" mean？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called as **Look-Back Conditions**

To specify a look-back dependency, enter the job name followed by a comma (,) then
HH (hours), period (.) and MM (minutes).

**Sample JIL**:

```
insert_job: test_sample_04
machine: localhost
command: sleep 10
condition: success(test_sample_01,12.00) AND failure(test_sample_02,24.00) AND
success(test_sample_03)
```

**Explanation**:

- The last run of `test_sample_01` completed successfully during the last 12 hours.
- The last run of `test_sample_02` completed with a FAILURE status during the last 24
  hours.
- The last run of `test_sample_03` completed successfully at any time.

**For User case**:

```
condition: e(job1,06.00) = 0 & e(job2,03.00) = 0
```

- The last run of `job1`completed with exit code of 0 in the last 6 hours
- The last run of `job2`completed with exit code of 0 in the last 3 hours

**Reference**:
[CA Workload Automation AE User Guide Release 11.3.6](https://ftpdocs.broadcom.com/cadocs/0/CA%20Workload%20Automation%20AE%20Release%2011%203%206%20-%20Public%20Access-ENU/Bookshelf_Files/PDF/WA_AE_User_ENU.pdf)